# Shell Script variables within multiple quotes

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I am running the following line within a shell script:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "$1"'
```

I want to be able to type the $1 using applescript. Is there any way for the $1 to come out as what I type in to the terminal after the script? Now, it just types literally $1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in single quotes, like this -

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke '$1''
```

Comment: Wow duh! Works best if i do it something like 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "'$1'"'

Comment: Yea, that "'$1'" will quote your input parameter. If that's what you need then you can use that too.